# inverse() vs pinv() which one good for linear system

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse, linear-equation

I have a linear system `A*x=b`. Here `x` is the unknown value, so I have to solve for `x`. `A` is a sparse matrix whose diagonal and off-diagonal elements have some non-zero values. The other elements is zero or close to zero.

Using MATLAB, I have two options

1. `x = inv(A) * b`
2. `x = A \ b`

But both give me NaNs in the result. I know this will happen because `A` is a sparse matrix. So, I tried `pinv()` which is pseudo-inverse. This time I got some results.

Is it OK to use pseudo-inverse in a situation like this, where inverse has failed to produce a result? What type of result does pseudo inverse produce? Is it reliable or it is a form of error?

Comment: Stack Overflow does not deal with discussion threads. It's a Q&A site. And unless you show what you are actually doing, it's going to be difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Oh thank you so much to remind me. I think I already discuss a problem. I got when NaN when using inv () instaed of pinv (). So is it good to using pinv () in place of inverse ().

Comment: To be more specific, can you provide a small sample input that demonstrates your problem? It would be much easier to help you if I had something to play with. Having a sparse matrix with a non-zero diagonal is usually great for finding a solution, so some specifics would really help.

Comment: Ok I will create another thread where I give the details of code blocks and matrices dimensions.

Comment: Please don't do that. It's not a discussion thread but a single standalone question. Please edit what you have by clicking the edit button below the question. It is quite salvageable, just needs more concrete information.

Comment: By the way, I hope you don't mind the edits I've already made. I normalized the language and formatting a bit, hopefully without changing your original intent in any way.